# Can a USB 3.1 type c dock work on a USB 3.1 type A?

Tags: laptop, usb-3, docking-station, usb-c

I have a laptop that has two USB 3.1 type A ports and I want to use a dock on it to expand its IO's to use more than one external display on it.

The problem is that every affordable dock that supports multiples display is type C. So it's possible with an adapter to use one of this docks on my laptop?

Comment: It highly depends on which alternative mode your dock requires. Say your dock need your computer stream display port data through type C then the USB A adapter won't work. Other modes like thunderbolt is similar. Type A adapter only works if you dock is pure USB and doesn't need too much power than Type A can provide.

Comment: Be careful. A lot of docks that use a USB Type-C connector are for the MacBook market and are really Thunderbolt 3 docks, so they won't work, or won't be fully functional, with a machine that can only do USB 3.1 and not Thunderbolt 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters to convert between USB C and A do exist.

You may for example in amazon.com issue the query "usb type-a to type-c"
to find many types of such adapters.

It's up to you to find one that fits your dock and laptop.
The adapters are usually cheaper than the dock,
so I suggest to buy the dock (and adapter if possible) from a seller
that has a nice return policy, such as Amazon.